# How to copy the records which are not in the target datastore using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a table in sql and it is copied to ADLS. After copying, sql table got inserted with new rows. I wanted to get the new rows.

I tried to use join transformation. But I couldn't get the output. What is the way to achieve this.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have tried and what you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-portal#create-a-pipeline). Using this you can get newly added rows from sql to data lake storage. Reproduced issue from my side and able to get newly added records from pipeline.

1. Created two tables in sql storage with names data_source_table and watermarktable.
2. data_source_table  is the one which is having data in table and watermarktable used for tracking new records based date.
3. Created pipeline as shown below,
   [image]

In lookup1 selecting the datasource table

In lookup2 select Query as follows

```
     MAX(LastModifytime) as NewWatermarkvalue from data_source_table;
```

[image]

Then in copy activity source and sink taken as shown below images

SOURCE:

[image]
Query in Source:

```
 select `* from data_source_table where LastModifytime > '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}' and LastModifytime <= '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Watermarkvalue}'
```

SINK:
[image]

Pipeline ran successfully and data in sql table is loaded into data lake storage file.
[image]

Inserted new rows inserted in data_source_table and able to get those records from Lookup activity
[image]